# Insert into MYSQL database using INSERT SELECT and VALUES

Tags: mysql, select, insert

Here I am trying to insert a new row into a table (calls). The only value I'm trying to get is caller_id from the callers table, the rest are all strings that i already have.

Im not sure what im doing wrong. caller_id is a foreign key if I'm not mistaken.

```
                        string initialcalls = "INSERT INTO calls (is_outbound, is_active, start_time, dealer_no, caller_id,call_id, is_spam, is_voicemail) SELECT"
                            + "'@is_outbound', '@is_active', '@start_time', '@dealer_no', @caller_id, '@call_id',  '@is_spam', '@is_voicemail' FROM callers WHERE callers.id = @fone;";
                        MySqlCommand initialCall = new MySqlCommand(initialcalls, connection);
                        string dealerNO = Regex.Match(items[10], @"\d+").Value;



                        initialCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@is_outbound", isOutBound);
                        initialCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@is_active", is_active);
                        initialCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start_time", datetimeSQLstart);

                        initialCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dealer_no", dealerNO);
                        initialCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caller_id", selectforcallerid);
                        initialCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@call_id", items[0]);
                        initialCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fone", items[8]);

                        initialCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@is_spam", isSpam);
                        initialCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@is_voicemail", isVoiceMail);


                        initialCall.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        this.CloseConnection();
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert and Select must be done on two completely separate queries.

```
INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2) VALUES (value1, value2);

SELECT field1, field2 FROM tablename WHERE something > something else;
```

You've got to reference the foreign table to use a foreign key.

```
SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2 FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: hmmmm, well if i try to assign the foreign key it errors out, but if i don't assign it, it gets a null value. not sure what my major malfunction is.